# Which regular expression can be used to recognize keywords in java?

Tags: java, regex, keyword

I want to match keywords like if,else,new,and..etc.Please suggest an appropriate regular expression to match them.

I have tried with

```
(((\\s)+(when|then|end|and))+(\\s|$))|rule|if|else|(new+(\\s))
```

but it is not working properly.

Comment: How far have you gotten in your attempts? Why are you trying to match Java keywords?

Comment: A regular expression can't do that; it requires a recursive-descent parser.

Comment: You can store the key word in some collection, regex need some patter that is missing in keywords

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it cannot be answered.

Comment: @chrylis: To be fair, Sana didn't say that the regex shouldn't be matching the keywords if they appear in a comment or a string or some other situation where they might not act as a keyword.

Comment: I didn't mean all keywords.just need some particular ones.Now I have tried with (((\\s)+(when|then|end|and))+(\\s|$))|rule|if|else|(new+(\\s)) .but it is not working properly

Comment: Use `\b` instead of `\s`.

Comment: @chrylis - It would be more accurate to say "This question cannot be answered because 5 people believe it's off-topic" than the other way around.

Comment: What is it that is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list a Java keywords, then you can turn it into a regex that matches those keywords like this (in principle - the following isn't meant to be used as actual code, just to illustrate how it works):

```
"\\b(?:" + "if" + "|" + "for" + "|" + ... + "|" + "new" + "|" + "static" + ")\\b"
```

That regex uses [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to make sure it doesn't match `if` in the word `knife`, for example.

It has no concept of semantics, though, so unless you have already done some parsing to separate comments or strings etc. from the "command parts" of the source code, then you will find matches in places where they are not necessarily being used as keywords.

Comment: This is a very good answer.  But if you are going to use it, please make sure you understand the last paragraph completely.